# Drupal JSON:API core module. Can't use Authorization

Tags: drupal, json-api

I've a drupal installation and use RESTer, an firefox plugin for testing. `GET localhost/drupal/jsonapi/node/article` works.

```
POST localhost/drupal/jsonapi/node/article
Accept application/vnd.api+json
Content-Type application/vnd.api+json
Authorization Basic uzuzgizgi
```

Works only if i use the `Authorization Basic uzuzgizgi` part, even if the resource is available from public by permission, so no problem. If i set the permission to authenticated user the `POST` is'nt working any more even if i submit the right user:password inside `Authorization Basic ....`  ErrorCode 403 Forbidden. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How you are Submitting the Authorization Header? 
It Should be Basic HTTP Authentication Means Base64 Encode of username:password

Comment: Are you sure your `token` is valid? 

`Authorization Basic token`

Comment: That's not completely True. Before you chose between JSON API and REST API in Drupal 8, you should have read the difference between them. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/jsonapi-vs-cores-rest-module 
They clearly states that `Choose REST if you have non-entity data you want to expose. In all other cases, choose JSON:API.` You should have stick with REST API if your application needs flexible API. JSON API is only for exposing the current Entity Data of Drupal in JSON Specification. They are actually bulky and may contain reduntant information.

Comment: It is overwhelming to develop Decoupled Drupal at First. But they are very powerful and flexible. For Example, you can use GatsbyJS Framework to build websites which delivers fast user experience.

Comment: 'Overwhelming' would not be my word of choice.

Comment: Ok.No issues. No Hard Feelings. For me, it was overwhelming and I mean it in a positive way!